# PC crashes to gray screen while playing a game. After restarting, blue dots appear on screen

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, display, crash

After launching a game (Halo 5: Forge), my PC crashes to a gray screen where I have to force a shutdown. After restarting, blue dots appear on my screen.

I've attempted to fully remove all NVIDIA drivers and reinstall via GeForce Experience, but the issue still occurs.

I've attached an image of my specs I'm referring to. I'm glad to provide any more information. Thanks for helping.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HFPV.jpg)

Comment: It sounds like the graphics card is overheating or faulty.  You should monitor the temperatures.

Comment: Temperatures seemed to stay around 40C when the crash happened.